# Launch bitcoind at startup on Ubuntu

Tags: bitcoind, ubuntu

I have `bitcoind` installed on my VPS runing Ubuntu 18.04, and I want to configure it to launch `bitcoind` on startup.

What the best way to do so with my configuration ?

Comment: There’s a suitable systemd configuration for bitcoind in the contrib directory.

Comment: Wanted to close this question but finally posted an answer as i could not fine a decent motivation (aside from "there is a major troll as the only answer" :p). Will also edit for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

To start `bitcoind` at startup on a system using systemd, use the [service configuration provided in contrib/init/](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/contrib/init/bitcoind.service) from the root of the bitcoin-core repository.

You can then manage `bitcoind` as any other systemd service (and possibly have some other rely on it, such as a Lightning Network implementation's service).

```
systemctl start bitcoind
systemctl stop bitcoind
# This enables launching the service at startup
systemctl enable bitcoind
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add a cron program that runs on startup, creates a temp file to say it has already ran, and then execute. This makes it so that every time cron tries to run the program, it turns out empty.

Example:

```
touch /tmp/btc.true
[ ! -f /tmp/btc.true ] && sudo -u $USER sh -c 'HOME=~$USER; bitcoind -daemon'
exit 0
```

Comment: That’s awful. There’s a @reboot flag for cron if you want to be hacky.

Comment: Ok, I'm noobie in this theme, I really dont understand so well... My main question is why not to use systemctl enable bitcoind?